# Using this pointer in const member function (C++)

Tags: c++, constants

I have a const member function `bar` from within I want to use the `this` pointer to call a function of a base class of `ClFoo`.

I get a compiler error though, saying:

```
'ClRDFoo::ReadCounterfile' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const ClFoo' to 'ClRDLFoo &'
```

These are the methods and classes:

//ClFoo.cpp

```
int ClFoo::bar( void ) const
{
    int nCounter = 0;
    this->ReadCounterFile(&nCounter);
}
```

//ClFoo.h

```
class ClFoo : public ClRDFoo
{
protected: 

      int ClFoo::bar( void ) const;

}
```

//ClRDFoo.h

```
  class ClRDFoo 
    {

    protected:
         virtual bool ReadCounterFile(void *pBuffer);

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to call a non-const member function, (`bool ReadCounterFile(void*)`), from a const one (`void bar() const`). This breaks const correctness and is not allowed.

You would have to make `ReadCounterFile` `const` or make `bar()` non-const.

Comment: Thank you. Havent really figured out constcorrectness 100%. I made `bar()` non-const but run into trouble now because `bar()` is passed as a function pointer to another function that requires it to be const.

Comment: @tzippy help with what? You are trying to do something that is not allowed. You have to re-design your code.

Answer (score 2):

Because `bar` is marked `const`, all it can do is call other functions *also* marked `const`. This is to ensure that you do not modify anything.

Answer (score 0):

From bar() function which is a constant, you are calling a non constant function ReadCounterFile(), which is not allowed